# CentOS - rsyslog and PHP - Log to remote, centralized server

Tags: php, centos, syslog

I'm working on a project with a small number of servers which host a PHP application. Right now each server is currently logging php errors, locally, to /var/log/php/oops.log, but I would like implement a solution where I can log into one, central server and view error log entries from any and all servers hosting the PHP application.

I've been doing some reading, and need a sanity check on the steps in order to accomplish my end game.

- Change php.ini error_log directive to log to 'syslog' instead of '/var/log/php/oops.log'
- Configure /etc/rsyslog.conf on each app server to filter PHP messages and forward them to a central (remote) server
- Configure central server to accept connections from all app servers (iptables etc)

My current system configuration is centos 6.2 (and a few .3) and all boxes use rsyslog.

Am I on the right track with the above steps? Anyone know of any step-by-step resources which may help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution I ended up going with is:

1. Configure each server's php.ini to log to syslog
2. Ensure every edge server can connect to remote server `syslog`
3. For every edge server, edit /etc/rsyslog.conf to log `local1.* @syslog`
4. On `syslog` server, edit /etc/rsyslog.conf to filter messages using [outchannels](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_conf_output.html) and [filters](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_conf_filter.html)

Now, when a php message is logged on an edge server, it gets sent to the centralized, remote server (syslog), where the message is parsed and filtered to an outchannel if certain criteria are met. This allows me to now only have to monitor one log file for all my edge servers.